# Catch error invalid namespace "root\SecurityCenter2"

Tags: powershell

Trying to retrieve the list of installed antivirus with on remote computers with below command.

```
Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\SecurityCenter2" -Class AntiVirusProduct
```

computer with antivirus shows installed antivirus details.
But

```
Invalid namespace “root\SecurityCenter2”
```

error is thrown if the computer do not have any antivirus trying to catch the error and export csv that computer has no antivirus

```
catch {
    Write-Warning "[ERROR] invalid namespace [$($computer)] : $_"
     $noantivirus+=$computer
}
$noantivirus | out-file -FilePath  c:\noantivirus.csv -Force
```

No luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't appear to be a terminating error so it wouldn't be caught in a try catch statement. Try catch statements only catch terminating errors so you will need to tell PowerShell to treat the non-terminating error as a terminating error by using `-ErrorAction Stop` like this:

```
try
{
    Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\SecurityCenter2" -Class AntiVirusProduct -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch
{
    Write-Warning "[ERROR] invalid namespace [$($computer)] : $_"
    $noantivirus+=$computer
}
$noantivirus | out-file -FilePath  c:\noantivirus.csv -Force
```